# Font awesome loads partially in Firefox (25% works and the rest shows unicode)

Tags: font-awesome

I've been struggling for hours now, to figure out why font-awesome isn't functioning properly. I used the Font Awesome Wordpress plug-in. It works for the majority of the browsers, however Firefox is showing only a few characters.

It's the magenta menu on this website: http://www.babystuf.nl. (the blocks in the left sidebar) I tried everything (updates to Font awesome 4.X without the plugin, added .htacess in the /font folder, changed the .. /fonts/ path to a static path). Without succes. 
Weirdest thing is, that we run a copy of that same website (http://www.baby-wereld.nl) and it's working fine there! Different server, same WP version, however with less plugins than babystuf.nl.

Who has an idea on how to fix this?
Thanks! M

UPDATE: It turned out that we used the All In One Event Wordpress plug-in, that uses Font Awesome as well… And that's a older version than 3.2.1. Only Firefox loaded that font set…

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. I thought I had tried EVERYTHING (htaccess, changing file paths, playing with permission, etc) but it turned out **I had previously tried to use a Font Awesome plugin in my wordpress installation** and Firefox was picking up this older version of FontAwesome. Disabling the plugin let the browser look for the files I had uploaded myself and the problem is now solved!